# Strange requests to web server

Tags: nginx, hosting

I have a VPS running Nginx, which currently serves only static content.

Once I was looking at the log and noticed some strange requests:

```
216.244.66.239 - - [03/Jan/2019:15:04:26 +0100] "GET /en/profile/Souxy HTTP/1.1" 200 4650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)"
216.244.66.239 - - [03/Jan/2019:15:04:28 +0100] "GET /en/view/8gIi2vad8Y HTTP/1.1" 200 4650 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)"
```

Comment: Have you finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is crawler. On this link is descriptin https://moz.com/help/moz-procedures/crawlers/dotbot. Maybe it is indexing your website.

You can block this requests on firewall or add file `robots.txt` with content

```
User-agent: dotbot
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikolaj ! it's very helpful ! this what i search.